# GeoServer with Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, gis, geoserver

We have created a website that is using GeoServer and Openlayers to create a mapping tool for some users. The app allows the users to add layers in GeoServer and these are presented in the web app for other users to consume.

We want the website to use the company Azure Active Directory to allow the users to have access. We have tried using the OAuth2 (google one) and LDAP plugin's for GeoServer to try to connect to Azure AD, however we cant get it to authenticate.

Is there a plugin for GeoServer to Azure AD or is there another plugin we can use instead.
Any help on the settings that are needed as well would also be helpful.

Comment: related?: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/oauth2/index.html#openid-connect-authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy to authenticate against AAD using **OIDC** and set the authenticated user in HTTP Header to use Header Authentication

You can configure Geoserver to use the built-in role service if you need AAD Authentication only

If you want to use AAD groups as roles in GeoServer you can make AAD groups as role claims in the token and in the proxy you can add these role claims in another header and configure GeoServer to accept those roles